# Fetch last medicines of all patients from data table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to fetch records of the Last Medicines of all patients from `NewPatient` table where booking date is today using Sql Query...

For example, if I entered 10 to 20  in two textboxes

1st textbox - 10

2nd textbox - 20

then it must show records of top 10 to 20 patients' last medicines in table `NewPatient` having booking date of today....

I am using **sql server** and **C#**.....

I tried something like this but this does not work

```
            try
            {
                SuperClass sc = new SuperClass();
                Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                rptPatients rpt = new rptPatients();// created report
                SqlCommand MyCommand = new SqlCommand();
                SqlDataAdapter myDA = new SqlDataAdapter();
                DB_DOCTORDataSet myDS = new DB_DOCTORDataSet();//created dataset
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\Raj\\Desktop\\doctor offline\\Webdigitronix.Homoeo.Library\\WebDigitronix.Homoeo.AppLayer\\bin\\Debug\\db\\DB_DOCTOR.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
                MyCommand.Connection = con;
                MyCommand.CommandText = "WITH T AS(SELECT TOP " + txtTo.Text + "  NP.*, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS RN from NewPatient NP where  BookingDate = '" + dtpBookingDate.Value.Date + "' and isvalid='true' and  medicine!='' and id=(select MAX(id) from newpatient where medicine!='' and isvalid='true'))SELECT * from T where RN>= " + txtFrom.Text + "";
                MyCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                myDA.SelectCommand = MyCommand;
                myDA.Fill(myDS, "NewPatient");
                rpt.SetDataSource(myDS);
                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

//Table Structure

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[newpatient] (
 [id]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
 [serialno]    VARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
 [patientname] VARCHAR (100) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__patie__1273C1CD] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [age]         INT           CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatient__age__1367E606] DEFAULT ((0)) NULL,
 [address]     VARCHAR (100) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__addre__145C0A3F] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [symptoms]    VARCHAR (MAX) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__sympt__15502E78] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [medicine]    VARCHAR (MAX) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__medic__164452B1] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [bookingdate] DATETIME      NULL,
 [alloteddate] DATETIME      NULL,
 [village]     VARCHAR (MAX) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__villa__173876EA] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [thana]       VARCHAR (MAX) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__thana__182C9B23] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [district]    VARCHAR (MAX) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__distr__1920BF5C] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [state]       VARCHAR (MAX) CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__state__1A14E395] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
 [isvalid]     BIT           CONSTRAINT [DF__newpatien__isval__1B0907CE] DEFAULT ('') NULL,
CONSTRAINT [pk_id_newpatient] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
```

Comment: You really need to avoid concatenating strings to form your sql queries. It leaves you wide open to sql injection attack. Take a moment to learn about parameterized queries and use those instead.

Comment: Not an answer, but in SQL the operator for inequality is `<>` not `!=`

Comment: @Steve `<>` is ANSI standard and `!=` is not ANSI standard but both are acceptable in sql server :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `PatientID` is some column that uniquely identify a patient and `SomeDateColumn` is a datetime/date column determine when the record was added.

```
;WITH LastMeds
AS
 (
 SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY SomeDateColumn DESC)
 FROM newpatient
 WHERE isvalid='true' AND isold='true' 
 AND serialno= @Var AND medicine!=''
 )
SELECT TOP N * FROM LastMeds
WHERE rn = 1
AND CAST(bookingdate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

**To Limit the Records Returned** (Using values passed in Textbox 1 and 2)

you can do something like this

```
;WITH LastMeds
AS
 (
 SELECT * , rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PatientID ORDER BY SomeDateColumn DESC)
 FROM newpatient
 WHERE isvalid='true' AND isold='true' 
 AND serialno= @Var AND medicine!=''
 ),
 RecordsRtn
 AS
  (
  SELECT *, rn2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PatientName)
  FROM LastMeds
  WHERE rn = 1
  )
SELECT  *
FROM RecordsRtn
WHERE rn2 >= (@TextBox1) AND rn2 <= (@TextBox2)
AND CAST(bookingdate AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
```

Comment: Extra credit if you add the "top 10 to 20 patients" and "booking date is today" code as requested by the OP. And you probably want to order the row number by descending date.

Comment: wt about serialNo=@var ?? its unique for every patient...they have no patientID.....

Comment: @RahulSharma I thought you were passing some variable value there, if  not just pass hardcoded the value there.

Comment: @RahulSharma is patient Name the only column that is used to identify a patient uniquely ??? use all the columns that are used to identify a patients uniquely in your table in the PARTITION BY clause of this query.